# What should we do when SKPaymentTransactionState is SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I am integrating inApp in my application when I tried to purchase product using Sandbox user I am getting state as  "SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing". What should I do?. I was able to purchase the same product earlier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was I was not observing payment queues during app launch. My issue got rectified once I did the same. The reason for issue was after purchasing the pack I was killing the application before finishing the transaction ie     [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction] was never getting called. I added the code for observing inApp transaction ie         [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
 during app launch and - (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions was getting called on app launch.

Comment: This is correct. Took me a while to find it, but this is the way [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2387/_index.html) recommends doing it

Answer (score 6):

The `SKPaymentQueue` receives a few different of `transactionState`'s. And `SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing` just notifies your app that the iTunes is making a purchase. Normally you can just ignore this unless you want to display something to the user while the purchase is in progress.

You should be more interested in `SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased` state which is triggered once the purchase is complete.